# Write $\frac{1}{x}$ as natural power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to express $\frac{1}{x}$  as a natural power series (whose expoents are $0,1,2,3,\dots$) for every $x$ different from zero?

Comment: No. The domain of convergence in $\Bbb R$ of a power series is always an interval, and  $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is not.

Comment: Yes, though the power series can't be centered at zero. For example, $1/x = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n (x-1)^n$ for $x\in(0,2)$.

Comment: It depends what you mean:  $\dfrac1x = \dfrac1a - \dfrac{x - a}{a^2} + \dfrac{(x - a)^2}{a^3 } - \cdots$ for $0 \lt x \lt 2a$

Comment: $1/x$ has no Taylor expansion around $x=0$ as all derivatives are infinite.

Comment: $ \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x\color{red}{+1-1}} = \frac{1}{1-(1-x)} = \sum_{n\ge0}(1-x)^n \space\colon |1-x|\lt1 $